# Magento: New website with redirects from old but still need admin access on old site(s)

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect

We have set up a new Magento2 wesite for a client. They have several old Magento1 websites which need to be redirected to this site so I have set up standard 301 redirects in .htaccess to the new site. So far so good.

Problem is the client still wants admin access to the old magento sites to view orders and sales info etc.  Now a simple exception on the .htaccess redirect for '^/admin' does and just ends up redirecting to index.php on the new site. Note that I have left the original magento redirects in place.

Is there anyway round this? 
Here is what I have added so far - this is in place before Magento redirects.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.co\.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.newsite\.co\.uk\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah found out from another site, this works with admin url http://oldsite.co.uk/index.php/admin

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/skin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/media
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php/admin
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.newsite/$1 [R=301,L]
```